# NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element while trying to locate an element using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have a specific login button I can't access with Python Firefox Selenium. It's the login button on this webpage: https://schalter.asvz.ch/tn/lessons/39616

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04, Python 3.5.2, Firefox 65.0 and Selenium 3.141.

I tried several combinations of approaches I found here on stackoverflow including the following:

```
login = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='btn btn-default ng-star-inserted']")

login = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-default ng-star-inserted']")

login = driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn btn-default ng-star-inserted')

login = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(., 'Login')]")

login = driver.find_element_by_name('app-lessons-enrollment-button')
```

But none of them worked. Always resulting in:

> NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element:
>   //*[@class='btn btn-default ng-star-inserted']

What is so different with this button? How can I make it work?

Comment: A good post so  +

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message...

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //*[@class='btn btn-default ng-star-inserted']
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to locate the desired element through the locator you have used.

---

Virtually, your first two(2) locators were just perfecto.

However, the desired element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element so to locate the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.btn.btn-default.ng-star-inserted[title='Login']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn-default ng-star-inserted' and @title='Login']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Good answer using `WebDriverWait` and the `and` in the Xpath!

Comment: This is perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Try the below option.

```
Login=driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.ng-star-inserted")
```

Or try this

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'button.ng-star-inserted'))).click()
```

You need following imports for option 2.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: First option gives me No Such Element Exception. Second one gives me a Timeout Exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below xpath:

```
xpath = "//button[@title='Login']"
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath);
element.click();
```

Comment: `xpath = "//button[@title='Login']` would also work fine (have tried it). `i` tag doesn't need to be appended.

Comment: Also gives me a No Such Element Exception.

Answer (score 0):

Following xpath works just fine (tested using selenium java)

```
//button[@title='Login']
```

I was able to locate and click the button.

Comment: Also gives me a No Such Element Exception